# javascript dos console cin like function witout prompt

Tags: javascript, console, dos

im creating a small javascript dos like console.
i have the blinking bar,add typed text(without inputs,using body onkyup),print and cls.

i wanted to implement a cin like function something like:

`bla = cin>>'write somthing'`

`print('you wrote'+bla)`

ive got something working but its with prompt...

```
console_p.jin= function(text)
{
    console_p.jout(text);

    varval = prompt("bla");
    return varval;
}//end jin

b=console_p.jin('write stuff');

console_p.jout("you wrote"+b);//"like print"
```

it worlks fine but the thing is it breaks the filing of console and you need to click a batton...

i want somthing like this without leaving the console to some popup.

if you need more of my code to help me ill post it.

why am i doing it? well i like prototyping stuff in console, no graphics,gui etc,only logic and text(but i never tried something like this in js).

Comment: Can you save a functional example at http://www.jsfiddle.net ? These function names here aren't telling anything, if we can't see, how they are written.

Comment: ok http://jsfiddle.net/rolen1234/XuJrW/1/ but its so slow.
and to use the console click it and type

Comment: Unfortenately my keyboard (scandinavian) is not compatible with your code, I see `0` when `=` was pressed, numpad gives me letters etc.

Comment: you cant read it? well i just need something that holds everything waits for input and insert it(the input) into variable. prompt worked but i don't want popups.