# javascript alternative to prompt function

Tags: javascript

i need somthing like cin in c++;

there's prompt, but the popup ruins the experience(and hides some of the page,and doesn't let you scroll).

i know how to use inputs ive used javascript for a year or so and have programming background.

what i need is a function that creates an input in a certain div, and then waits for user input and dosnt execute any other code until he gets the text the user submited.

somthing like.

```
var a = cin("#somediv","enter text here");
alert(a);
```

what happend with my last try was alert that says "null";
meaning it just executed witout waiting for input.

Comment: Your `cin` function will have to accept a callback, and then call that when the user is done, rather than attempting to block. You can't create functions like `prompt` that actually stop the JavaScript and make it wait on the function while the user does something. And you don't want to, partially for the reasons you identified. :-)

Comment: What you're looking for is a modal dialog box. If you search, you'll find quite a large number of options.

Comment: Now I understand your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17550398/1169519) : ).

Comment: Please don't post multiple copies of the same question. If you're not getting an answer to your previous question, use the "edit" link to fix it. You should delete this question.

Comment: Teemu : with a scandinavian keyboard? im impressed.
 T.J. Crowde:thanks ill do that. i dont want to spam stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

The function is acually called [prompt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp)

```
var bananas = prompt("Please type how many bananas you'd like");
alert("Here you have "+ bananas +" number of bananas. Smile!");
```

If you want to make an input field locking the page, you would have to make some sort of overlay on the page, and display the input on top of that; disabling the user for any other interaction but the field.

**EDIT:** By overlay I mean something like this:

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="overlay"></div>
        <form id="field">
            <input type="text" name="test" />
            <input type="submit" value="Continue" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#overlay {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}
#field {position:absolute; width:200px; height:200px; top:50%; left:50%; margin:-100px 0 0 -100px; z-index:10;}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#field').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Do some validation and such, and when done, hide the overlay and field
    $('#field, #overlay').hide();
});
```

Comment: he doesn't want to use prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this manually with JavaScript and HTML. This is something popular actually, so check [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/%E2%80%8E), it has means to create dialogs that are flexible and which you can style unlike prompt.